# java.net.SocketTimeoutException at peak traffic on Production

Tags: java, crashlytics, connection-timeout, akamai, socket-timeout-exception

We have been facing this issue on Prodcution. Now this issue occurs whenever  a notification is rolled out to all the Mobile Apps and Desktop Apps. In the notification one image is there which is cached at CDN(Akamai). So a lot of users are getting the following exception. I tried to figure out the issue but a lot of people say it might be due to
network issue on the device but my question is DNS of XXXX.XXXX.com has been resolved to akamai ip (117.239.141.27). So, that should not be a problem. Moreover I had a work with Akamai guys they couldn't find any issue at their end. So, I have following questions:

1) How do i figure out what is causing the issue? Secondly, does anyone has faced the similar issue on production at peak traffic?

2)  As mentioned in the below stack track which i got from crashlytics. In few cases we are getting private client ip (192.168.1.33) why is it so?
Shouln't public ip of client should be logged in the crashlytics.

```
Caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to XXXX.XXXX.com/117.239.141.27 (port 80) from /192.168.1.33 (port 50974) after 15000ms
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1416)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1368)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:488)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:434)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:565)
       at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:125)
       at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load$71fa0c91(NetworkRequestHandler.java:6)
       at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:72)
       at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.utils.AppNotificationHandler.getTabCategoryIdForScreen(AppNotificationHandler.java:82)
       at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.utils.AppNotificationHandler.handleExtras(AppNotificationHandler.java:806)
       at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.fcm.FCMIntentService.onMessageReceived(FCMIntentService.java:112)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(FirebaseMessagingService.java:394)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(zzg.java:26)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(zza.java:7)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: If the client is connected through wifi , you will always get private ip. So that is not the issue.

Comment: Check if there are any firewalls that are blocking the access.